# Which pom dependency should I use for jar commons-lang.jar

Tags: maven, maven-3, dependency-management

How do I know which version of a pom dependency I should use if its version is not in the jar name. For example the jar commons-lang.jar, what version of the pom dependency should I use ?

Here are its search results on maven central repo - http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22net.sf.staccatocommons%22%20AND%20a%3A%22commons-lang%22

Comment: Are you sure that you use the correct group-id ? I'd prefer to use one from Apache (http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22commons-lang%22%20AND%20a%3A%22commons-lang%22)

Comment: But which version should I use ? I just have a jar named commons-lang.jar . Which version should I use ?

Comment: Did you try to open the JAR and look into the META-INF directory ? Sometimes the version is given there... If not, you'll have to use MD5 against the Apache directory (http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/lang/binaries/)

Comment: I had this problem when I first started using maven and I tried migrating another developer's old project to maven. yatskevich's answer was how I determined the version of most of my jars. In some cases I couldn't determine the version of the jar and had to make an educated guess. The good news is that maven convention is to always have versionId in the artifact name so you shouldn't have this problem ever again so long as you use maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are migrating to Maven and just have a bunch of jars then you can try examining their `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` files inside of those jars.

I've just opened `commons-lang.jar` and saw the following in its `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`:

```
...
Implementation-Title: Commons Lang
Implementation-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Vendor-Id: org.apache
Implementation-Version: 2.4
...
```

So you can use `Implementation-Version` as your version in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Lots of jars dont have that info in the manifest file. Thats when you use the sha1 checksum trick in my answer...

Answer (score 7):

First, use the one from Apache.

Second, you have two options, the 2.x or 3.x branches; from searching [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/search.html?query=%22commons-lang%22):

**2.6**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**3.1**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're using Maven, you shouldn't have "just a jar", you should only know about POM dependencies.

(As of Feb 2014 it's up to 3.3.2, the 2.x series is still at 2.6. Note that you *may* use both in the same application because of their different packages.)

Answer (score 3):

While the other answers are correct a very handy way to find out exact match for an unknown jar where all you have is the jar itself and it does not contain a useful manifest is to create a sha1 checksum of the jar and then do a checksum search on http://search.maven.org in the Advanced Search at the bottom or on your own instance of a Nexus repository server that downloaded the index of the Central Repository.

And btw your search on central was incorrect since it had the wrong groupId as part of it. Here is a corrected link:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7C%22commons-lang%22